# Proper Design For SQL table connecting to many other tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, breeze

I have an app where users can log comments related to any specific entity that the system has and I wanted to know if there is a "best practice" way to handle the design of the db for this kind of feature.

For example: Three current entities (tables) deal are Question, Documentation, ReferenceMaterial (self explanatory what each hold).  The user can leave a comment on any one of those particular items and all comments are simply a varchar field, user id, and date of comment.  **EDIT**: Comments can also belong to more than one entity.  For example, all Question entities belong to a Quiz or Test entity.  Each of those (Quiz and Test), can also have comments associated with themselves.  So you could run a report to see all comments left for a test and easily just query the Comment table for every record with that test foreign key, or you could limit your query to just the comments left for questions in that test, or a particular question itself.  It offered a lot of flexibility **END EDIT**

Right now the way that I hvae this is one Comment table with a foreign key relationship with each of the other entity tables (i.e. fkQuestion, fkDocumentation, fkReferenceMaterial, etc).  So all comments in the system are stored in this table and based on what page the user is on, I conduct the join to that particular entity's records.

Is there a best practice way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have three foreign key fields in the multi-area Comment table that are nullable?  Or is there a junction table?  What's the advantage of using one Comment table instead of creating a Comment table for each area?  How often do you need to access all comments regardless of where they came from?

Comment: Sounds like your current method will leave many gaps... Perhaps a translation table is in order? A table containing a  Flag column (enumerated tables - 1=Question, 2=Doc., 3=Ref. Mat., or whatever), ID column (ID in flagged table), and Comment ID would lack holes and be easy to filter with a where statement on the flag.

Comment: @BaconBits - The design decision to go with one table instead of many to house comments was because a comment can also belong to a parent a "parent entity" so to speak.  For example, A Question Comment may want to be presented on a Report of all the comments left for a single test (imagine a comment left for the test and then a bunch of comments at the question level for each question on that test) test's comments.  Having it setup the way I have it now made it easy to go to one place to run every query regarding comments.  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Conduit - I updated my question because I left out an integral piece of the reasoning that led me to the current design.  That each Comment can belong to multiple tables.  I've never worked with a translation table in before, would that still work considering the edit?

Comment: I think so? I might be reading the edit incorrectly. Showing us your layout visually or making a sqlfiddle might help clarify your question a bit. I'll write an answer fleshing out my idea.

Comment: ...Nope - things get a little messy with a nested entity structure. Sorry.

Comment: @Conduit - Entity Structure is essentially: 
[Test] has many [Question] ; 
[Document] has 0 to many [Comment] .  
[Test] has 0 to many [Comment] .  
[Question] has 0 to many [Comment] .  

So a [Comment] that is assigned to a [Question] may still need to be retrieved when a [Test] report is generated.  And a [Comment] may be assigned to the parent [Test] entity alone without being related to any of the [Question] child entities .

The translation table sounds interesting though, is that a better way of structuring things?

Comment: Would it be possible to give each test, doc, question, etc. a "comment entity id"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70429/discussion-between-jakehova-and-conduit).